# Adding Text to Javascript Span id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have some code that populates a numerical value if greater than 1, and if not, it prints "In-Stock".

Comment: Add the relevant code pleaaase..

Comment: Provide the whole code please. what's the value in span ?

Comment: maybe I'm tired but I can't understand your question. `our_inventory` is an id, not a value.

Comment: don't edit you question so that it's totally blank. It's fine how it is

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```
var $inv = $('#our_inventory'), val = parseInt($inv.text(),10);
$inv.text(val>0?"Inventory:"+val:"In-Stock");
```

Comment: use prepend() method

Comment: That may have side effects depending on the css

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in the appropiate place of your jQuery script. You just need to use the [`.before`](https://api.jquery.com/before/) method from jQuery to place some text before the chosen element.

```
<script>
if(parseInt($('#our_inventory').text(),10) > 0)
    $('our_inventory').before("Inventory: ");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(()=>{
  
  var val = -5;
  trigger();
  $('#up').click(()=>{
     val++;
     $('#hnd').text(val);
   trigger();
  });

 $('#down').click(()=>{
       val--;
     $('#hnd').text(val);    
     trigger();
  });
  

function trigger(){
      var our_inventory_value = Number($('#hnd').text());
      $('#show').text(our_inventory_value);
    
     if(our_inventory_value<0){
      $('#our_inventory').text('in inventory');
     }else{
      $('#our_inventory').text(our_inventory_value);
     }

}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h3>Demo </h3>
  <button id='up'> up </button>
  <button id='down' >down </button>
  <br/>
  <span id="our_inventory" class="value"></span> <br/><br/>
   <span id="show" class="value"></span>
  <input type='hidden' id='hnd' value='-5'/>
  </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var inventory = $('#our_inventory').getAttribute(class);

if (inventory < 0) {
    $('#our_inventory').html('In-Stock');
    } else {
    $('#our_inventory').html('Inventory:' + inventory);
    }
```

Comment: what is `inventory`?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.